# Swagger UI does not get generated when WebMvcConfigurationSupport is present

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, swagger-ui, springfox

I am trying to generate Swagger UI  in my spring boot project. The JSON API docs are generated, however Swagger UI doesn't, at least I am getting 404 when I enter the swagger ui address.
My dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, when I remove this config (and do nothing else):

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new SomeEnumConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new AnotherEnumConverter());
    }
}
```

The Swagger UI works.
Does Swagger UI have a problem with converters? Is there a workaround for the problem?

Comment: Most likely what's going on is you're only allowed to have one `WebMvcConfigurer` and by implementing your own, you're disabling the configurer that Springfox is defining to enable the Swagger UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the @EnableWebMvc annotation

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

  @Override
  protected void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(new SomeEnumConverter());
    registry.addConverter(new AnotherEnumConverter());
  }
}
```

But I think the official way to configure WebMvc now is implementing WebMvcConfigurer. You can see several examples in the [official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html). I think it does not require @EnableWebMvc if you use Spring Boot.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  protected void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(new SomeEnumConverter());
    registry.addConverter(new AnotherEnumConverter());
  }
}
```

Comment: the second solution does the job, with WebMvcConfigurationSupport I had to initialize an extra resolver.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still looking for this, I got it running using `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` without the need of `@EnableWebMvc`.
I'm using OpenAPI 3.0, not Springfox, with following Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I initially just got the JSON and a 404 on the UI.

What ultimately worked was adding the right resource handlers to my `WebConfig` and configuring my `SecurityConfig` to allow unrestricted access for everyone.

The resource handlers in my `WebConfig`:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/4.10.3/swagger-initializer.js")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/4.10.3/index.html")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/4.10.3/swagger-ui.css")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/4.10.3/index.css")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/4.10.3/swagger-ui-bundle.js")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/4.10.3/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js");
}
```

Important was to add each one specifically (with version and everything, ** didn't work). Otherwise it wouldn't run in the cloud.

I also needed to add the paths `"/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**"` my `SecurityConfig` to allow access to these resources. So in my case I added those here:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(...
       .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "...")...
}
```

and:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "...");
}
```

Comment: it fixed swagger ui 404 issue , but swagger only shows petstore swagger apis , not the application rest controller apis.
have you faced this issue ?

Comment: @AzhaguSurya, soory for the late reply, didn't logged in for a while.
I remeber having the same problem, just seeing Petshop.
I either just changed the Docs with a dropdown or changed an URL or something.
I don't have acces to the source code anymore, to give some more details, sorry